# JQuery & jade read render data from Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am using Jade framework as frontend with Nodejs & express for backend

so when I am rendering a view with data i can't access these data using JQuery

below my service from Nodejs that renders a view with simple data = x

```
router.get('/test',function (req,res,next) {


    res.render('test',{data : 'x'});

});
```

so the test page will show without any problem, what am trying to do is to read the rendered data using Jquery methods

```
                footer
                .pull-right
                    | Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by
                    a(href='https://colorlib.com') Colorlib
                .clearfix
            // /footer content




    // jQuery
    script(src='/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
        alert(data) // no alert or action happen
```

but the error said (unknown variable of data)

Moreover, I can read it from jade itself

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following

```
|<script>
!='alert("'+data+'")'
|</script>
```

The JavaScript you are writing inside your jade framework will not be able to see your server side node.js variables because this client side JavaScript is loaded and executed inside the browser, so you have to pass your variables somehow from the server side to client side then obtain these variables using client side JavaScript.

If you are passing some strings , it is easier for you to use the previous way.

`|<script>` -> open the JavaScript tag.

`!='alert("'+data+'")'` -> normal jade string that will be inside our JavaScript tag , that means it should give us JavaScript code after being processed by jade which will make our final text `alert("x")` because data will be replaced by its value.

`|</script>` -> close The JavaScript tag

but if you want to pass object there are a ways to do so :

- Using AJAX requests.
- Use `JSON.stringify(data)` in server side to write your object to a hidden `div` and in client side using `var data = JSON.parse(jQuery('div').text())`

Comment: unfortunately didn't read the data and below the error 

profile:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at profile:2

Comment: modified my answer , try it now

Comment: oh wow it's working now !! but the problem is u tried to add my own code but couldn't !!! I tried to duplicate your code also can't 

| <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                                                !='alert("' + services + '")'
                                                                                !='alert("' + services + '")'
                                                                                | </script>

so what is the secret here ??

Comment: added some explanation in my answer